# Condense several dataframes in one MultiIndex column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have several dataframes with columns (letters) that are a subset of all my letters and time indexes for different periods. For each period, I have several dataframes with different information (numbers) of my letters.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'], columns=['A', 'C'])
df_1b = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=['2019-01-03', '2019-01-04'], columns=['A', 'B'])
df_2a = pd.DataFrame([[5, 0, 6], [7, 8, 8]], index=['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df_2b = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [8, 8]], index=['2019-01-03', '2019-01-04'], columns=['B', 'C'])
```

I want to obtain all information in one master dataframe `df_master` which would have a structure like this:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'],[1, 2]], names=['Letters', 'Numbers'])

df_master = pd.DataFrame(index=['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04'],  columns=columns)
```

What is the best way to obtain this final dataframe from the previous ones?

---

I have managed to do it column by column, but I have a feeling there must be a more efficient way to do it.

What I did for each dataframe (in a loop):

```
for letter in df_1a.columns.unique():
    df_master.loc[df_1a.index, pd.IndexSlice[letter, 1]] = df_1a[letter]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your naming scheme makes it a little difficult. But here's a solution:

```
(pd.DataFrame({k:pd.concat(ds, sort=True).stack() 
                  for k,ds in enumerate([(df_1a, df_1b), (df_2a, df_2b)],
                                        start=1)})
   .unstack()
   .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
              A         B         C     
              1    2    1    2    1    2
2019-01-01  1.0  5.0  NaN  0.0  2.0  6.0
2019-01-02  3.0  7.0  NaN  8.0  4.0  8.0
2019-01-03  1.0  NaN  2.0  5.0  NaN  6.0
2019-01-04  3.0  NaN  4.0  8.0  NaN  8.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However I don't really understand what you're doing inside of pd.DataFrame().